# How to remove matched attribute in each and every matched element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#quote_test_item_ids').removeAttr('disabled');
```

.removeAttr(AttrName) above only removes 'disabled' attribute in first matched element #quote_test_item_ids. There are more than one #quote_test_item_ids in the html page. How to remove each and every attribute 'disabled' on the html page?

Comment: It is illegal to have two elements with the same ID.  IDs must be unique.

Comment: @Alnitak, "illegal" is a perfectly valid word in this context.  It doesn't only apply to law enforcement.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I think that was supposed to be a joke =/

Comment: BTW the id was automatically generated by the rails view and unfortunately they are not unique. I checked twice and they are the same.

Comment: @Rocket, that would imply it was a pun.  I had been trying to give Alnitak the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have multiple elements with the same ID.  That's a no-no.  IDs are supposed to be unique.  Change them to classes instead, then do:

```
$('.quote_test_item_ids').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Since IDs are unique, `$('#quote_test_item_ids')` returns the 1st (since there shouldn't be others).  You can cheat a bit by using the attribuite selector:

```
$('[id="quote_test_item_ids"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: All attribute 'disabled' were removed by using html tag select. Couldn't make it work with class and id#. html tag is the easy way to remove the attribute. Here is the code:    $('select').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
  });

Comment: `$('select').removeAttr('disabled');` should be slightly faster :-P

Comment: Yes, $('select') picks each and every one, even without .each().

Answer (score 1):

If you make "quote_test_item_ids" a class attribute of the divs, then you can do the following:

```
$("div.quote_test_item_ids").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: You don't need `each`.  `removeAttr` will act on all elements in the set.